# How to replace a specific number of characters in between two known characters?

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed, terminal

I have the following string:

```
NA.|NA.|the NA. company|theNAcompany|2.7737|1.4874|NA|NA|NA
```

Using the command sed in OSX, I need to replace all the NA that are between the characters | with, say, FOO. Only the characters between | that contain only NA are to be replaced. Thus, the correct result would be

```
NA.|NA.|the NA. company|theNAcompany|2.7737|1.4874|FOO|FOO|FOO
```

where the "NA."s are left alone.

So far I've tried:

```
sed -e 's/[?<=\|](NA)[?=\|]/FOO/g'
sed 's/\|NA\|/\|FOO\|/g'
```

but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` does not have lookahead, let alone lookbehind. Use a more powerful tool.

```
echo "NA.|NA.|the NA. company|theNAcompany|2.7737|1.4874|NA|NA|NA" |\
perl -pne "s/(\||^)NA(?=\||$)/\1FOO/g"
```

or

```
echo "NA.|NA.|the NA. company|theNAcompany|2.7737|1.4874|NA|NA|NA" |\
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="NA")$i="FOO";print}'
```

Comment: Suppose I wanted to turn:
    
    **awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="NA")$i="FOO";print}'**

into the function remove_na() so that 

    **bash remove_na_func.sh remove_na input_file.txt output_file.txt**

will process the text file input_file and save the results in output_file. Any suggestions on the best way to do this? I actually tried and couldn't get it to work. I need this because I'll need to execute the script within another program to do some data preprocessing.

Comment: `awk '...' <"$1" >"$2"` inside `remove_na_func.sh` should do it.